# How to change the color of the values and the ticks of the cbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, colorbar

I have this [heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W79TC.png) and I would like to change the color of the ticks and the values of the cbar. I don't know if there is a parameter in the cbar_kws but I don't seem to find it. Thank you in advance!

[image: heatmap]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is to temporarily set the [rc context](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) like so:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)

plot_context = {
    "ytick.color": "red",
    "xtick.color": "blue",
    "ytick.major.width": 5,
}

with plt.rc_context(rc=plot_context):
    ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
```

Which produces:

[image: heatmap with custom coloured yticks]

I've also increased the size of the `ytick.major.width` so you can see the colour easier.